# Should I use webRTC alongside Socket.IO if I want a live chat ability beside the real-time video streaming?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, webrtc, video-streaming

What I am trying to do is to create a simple virtual classroom project like Adobe connect, but obviously simpler, using `Flutter` and `NodeJS`, and I need the following options:

1. Real-time video or only voice streaming
2. Live chat box
3. Screen sharing ability
4. File sharing ability(Like PDF or PowerPoint or other text/doc files)
5. Whiteboard

As I searched so far I found that it seems `WebRTC` works for video/voice streaming and also screen sharing as well.

Also most of the livechat projects using `Socket.IO`.

My main question here is to know can I use only `WebRTC` for both real-time video/voice streaming and also live chat as well? Is it a good idea or it's better to combine `Socket.IO` and `WebRTC` together?

Furthermore I want to know can I use each of those libraries for File-Sharing purposes?

Answer (score 6):

WebRTC gives you lower latency and a lot of functionality for conferencing out of the box. So for video/audio calls and screen sharing this is definitely a better choice.

Also, there's an option to use p2p communication which reduces latency even more and saves you resources on the server-side. Though if you intend to support many participants it looks less beneficial - you will need to maintain `n-1` connections for each user if you have `n` users in total.

For live chat, whiteboard and file sharing there would be no big difference in terms of performance.
Things to consider:

- WebRTC is more complex technology than websockets to setup and support
- There might be opensource solutions for this features, i would make a decision based on what you can reuse in your project
- You can use WebRTC for some of the features and websockets for others

> can I use only WebRTC for both real-time video/voice streaming and
> also live chat as well

Yes you can, there's a [RTCDataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel) interface for exchanging arbitrary data. It can be used for live chat / whiteboard / file transfer.

As a good example, there's an opensource project [peercalls](https://peercalls.com), that implements chat and file transfer via WebRTC through the same connection that is used for conferencing.

Websockets can be used for file transfer as well, check out [this library](https://github.com/vincentdieltiens/WebSocketFileTransfer).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information and introducing `peer-calls` project. Please let me know if you know any similar project for the whiteboard as well.

Comment: I don't know any well-supported webrtc+whiteboard projects. As for websockets whiteboards, this one looks promising: https://github.com/excalidraw/excalidraw

Comment: For conferencing, you should also check out janus videoroom. It is used in many projects including educational platforms, might be a good starting point as well. https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videoroomtest.html

Answer (score 1):

Using WebRTC requires signaling server and signaling is often implemented using websocket, check this mdn article [Signaling and video calling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling)

And with websocket you can implement livechat too, so it is not an either or situation but both quite often.